# How do I set permissions for user roles in the install profile

Tags: nodes, installation, users

I have a content type which I am creating on install profile, and I want to create a user that has permissions to edit that content type. How do I create user roles and permissions for those roles in the install profile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add a role you can use [`user_role_save()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_role_save/7):

```
$role = new stdClass();
$role->name = 'role_name';
$role->weight = 5;
user_role_save($role);
```

To grant specific permissions to a role you can use [`user_role_grant_permissions()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_role_grant_permissions/7):

```
$grant = array('access content', 'access comments', 'etc...');
user_role_grant_permissions($role->rid, $grant);
```